# Безопасность кода авторизации?

Tags: php, pdo

подскажите по моему коду авторизации. Он безопасен? И стоит его переписать на PDO, и как лучше это сделать для новечка?

```
    <?php
session_start();
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/engine/data/main_config.php');
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/engine/core/mysql_connect.php');
if($_POST['response']) {
  $captcha = $_POST['response'];
  $secret = "6LfZjeIbAAAAALhKqTKfXlB14lAb7kYrBwuDs-5j";
  $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=". $secret . "&response=" . $captcha), true);
if(!$json['success']) {
     echo '<center>Неизвестная ошибка</center>';
     include('algo.php');
     die();
}
 }  else {
   echo '<center><div class="form-block-error"><b>Хмм. Докажите что вы не бот :)</b></div></center>';
   include('algo.php');
   die();
}
 $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM dle_users WHERE name LIKE '".$_POST['login']."'");
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   $password_mysql = $mysqli->query("select password from dle_users where name='".$_POST['login']."'")->fetch_object()->password;
   $realname = $mysqli->query("select name from dle_users where name='".$_POST['login']."'")->fetch_object()->name;
   if (!password_verify(urldecode($_POST['password']), $password_mysql)) {
        echo '<center><div class="form-block-error"><b>Вы ввели неправильный пароль, попробуйте еще раз или восстановите пароль!</b></div></center><script>grecaptcha.reset();</script>';
} else {
    $_SESSION['login'] = $realname;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
}
} else {
echo '<center><div class="form-block-error"><b>Данный логин еще не зарегистрирован</b></div></center><script>grecaptcha.reset();</script>';
}
include('algo.php');

?>
```

Comment: Нет не безопасен. Кидаться сразу на PDO нет смысла (хотя и можно) потому что ты  имея в распоряжении библиотеку, которая может тебя обезопасить - не применяешь её должным образом. Поэтому тебе и PDO сейчас не поможет. Для начала научись этим драйвером пользоваться по правилам

Comment: А ещё почитай книги по PHP. Например Котерова - PHP 7.0 в подлиннике. Также Роберта Мартина - Чистый код. Потому что твой код ужасен

Comment: У вас иньекция прям в коде `LIKE '".$_POST['login']."'"`.